# Declaring a function expression in parent or child component?

Tags: reactjs

Say I have a child component, a product card, and a parent component, a product page.

Each product card component should have edit and delete functionality.

I was thinking what would be the right approach: to create delete and edit functions inside product card component, because they are only related to this component, or create delete and edit functions inside product page component, then pass these function to children.

I think it's not a good idea to create function inside children, because functions will be recreated for each children, maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: Very unlikely to make a difference. Don't bother unless you're actually running into slowness issues and really think this would be a cause (which it won't be)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the function is only used in the child component and it doesn't need any parent component data then the best practice is
to declare the function in the child component. If the function is used in many components and it depends on the parent state then you should declare the function in the parent component.